# Google Maps For Rails replaceMarkers not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, maps, gmaps4rails

Am I missing something obvious? Map keeps loading `@oldjson` which I set in the controller and won't be replaced when I set it in the view.

View code:

```
<% @json = Map.find_by_id('39').to_gmaps4rails %>
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @oldjson, "options" => { "draggable" => true } } ) %>
<script>    
  Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(<%= @json %>);
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you"re facing a js error with this current code.

The reason is the following:

- the js used and created by `gmaps4rails` is put within the `yield :scripts`
- so your additionnal js here is called before the map is created

Solution:

```
<% @json = Map.find_by_id('39').to_gmaps4rails %>
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @oldjson, "options" => { "draggable" => true } } ) %>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
 <script>    
  Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(<%= @json %>);
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok this makes more sense, getting a js error though of gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js:280 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fitBounds' of null. You know what could be causing this?

Comment: what version of the gem do you have?

Comment: Just thinking: it takes asynchronous time to create a map and it's markers. So your own code could still be triggered before the map itself is ready. That's why I created the callback method in which you can safely put whatever you need. See doc plz

Comment: Callback did the trick, had tried this before but with allong with your suggestion above this worked. Thanks very much.